# freebsd / mysql 5.5 high i/o usage

Tags: mysql, io, freebsd, disk

i have a problem.

i am using mysql5.5 on a freebsd8 server, with php 5.3.13 -fpm and nginx.

when i am looking at iostat -d 2, i see high disk i/o 20 30 mb/s in writes, however this does not translate in actual disk growth as far as i can see from monitoring df.

i looked at "top", and hit the m parameter to toggle and see which process is causing this disk activity and it shows it's the mysql server.

i don't know where to start here, because it's a bit puzzling for me on why this high disk write doesn't actually translate in disk usage being modified as well.

can you please throw me a hint to go on the right direction?

my hardware: dual quad core xeons / 4 x 120 gb ssd's in raid10 / 16 gb ram

below is my "my.cnf" file

```
    [mysqld]
datadir=/var/db/mysql
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking
skip-name-resolve
query_cache_limit=256M
query_cache_size=256M
query_cache_type=1
ft_min_word_len=3
max_user_connections=200
max_connections=200
interactive_timeout=10
wait_timeout=30
connect_timeout=10
thread_cache_size=128
long_query_time=5
key_buffer_size=1024M
join_buffer=2M
max_allowed_packet=16M
table_cache=32384
sort_buffer_size=4M
read_buffer_size=4M
max_connect_errors=10
thread_concurrency=8
myisam_sort_buffer_size=64M
low_priority_updates=1
concurrent_insert=2
max_heap_table_size=128M
tmp_table_size=128M
slow_query_log=1
slow_query_log_file=/var/db/mysql/razor-slow-log-by-katmai.log
long_query_time=1
log-queries-not-using-indexes
server-id=1
local-infile=0
innodb_open_files=131072
innodb_buffer_pool_size=8192M
#new options
#innodb_log_file_size=256M
#innodb_log_buffer_size=4M
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
#innodb_thread_concurrency=8
############################
#for recovery
#innodb_force_recovery=4
#innodb_file_per_table=

#[mysql.server]
#user=mysql
#basedir=/var/lib

[safe_mysqld]
err-log=/var/db/mysql/razor-mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/db/mysql/mysql.pid
open_files_limit=131072

#[mysqldump]
#quick
#max_allowed_packet=16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash

[isamchk]
key_buffer=64M
sort_buffer=64M
read_buffer=16M
write_buffer=16M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer=64M
sort_buffer=64M
read_buffer=16M
write_buffer=16M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard `iostat` display shows *combined* reads and writes:

```
foobox:~> iostat -d 2
          ada0             ada1              cd0              cd1 
KB/t tps  MB/s   KB/t tps  MB/s   KB/t tps  MB/s   KB/t tps  MB/s 
27.52   5  0.15  14.82   2  0.03   0.00   0  0.00   0.00   0  0.00 
96.00   1  0.14   0.00   0  0.00   0.00   0  0.00   0.00   0  0.00 
128.00   1  0.19   0.00   0  0.00   0.00   0  0.00   0.00   0  0.00 
64.00   3  0.19   0.00   0  0.00   0.00   0  0.00   0.00   0  0.00
```

So my guess is that you're not seeing writes at all, but rather reads.

To see them seperately you need to use the `-x` flag for extended statistics:

```
foobox:~> iostat -d -x 2
                        extended device statistics  
device     r/s   w/s    kr/s    kw/s qlen svc_t  %b  
ada0       1.9   3.6    51.3    98.5    0  37.6   1 
ada1       0.8   1.3     3.3    28.0    0  12.5   0 
cd0        0.0   0.0     0.0     0.0    0   0.0   0 
cd1        0.0   0.0     0.0     0.0    0   0.0   0 
pass0      0.0   0.0     0.0     0.0    0   0.0   0 
pass1      0.0   0.0     0.0     0.0    0   0.0   0 
pass2      0.0   0.0     1.1     0.0    0   0.0   0 
pass3      0.0   0.0     0.0     0.0    0   0.0   0
```

See the iostat manual page for a complete overview of the meaning of the headers, but kr/s is kilobytes read per second and kw/s is kilobytes written per second.